# How to replace a procedure in a module owned by other user?

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I'm trying to drop a stored-procedure in a module on DB2 LUW, but this module was created by another user.

When I use the code below:

`ALTER MODULE M1 DROP PROCEDURE P1`

I get the result:

"SQL Error [42501]: The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the required authorization or privilege to perform the operation."

Is there a way to grant acess to other user in a module? How could I work in a module that is not mine?